# I can no longer edit my question: Is there solid evidence regarding LBJ's possible involvement in JFK's murder?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Why do I have no longer have the ability to edit my question? Blocking the comments should not block my ability to edit the post, since I have been subjected to ridicule, particularly since I have very relevant, significant, sourced information to add to it.

Answer (score 4):

You no longer have the ability to edit the question (read *no one*, barring mods, has the ability to edit your question for the time being) because it has been locked by the mods.

Yes, locking a post does lock all features of the post including commenting, editing, voting, and answering.

The reason given was off-topic comments, which seems entirely valid given there were 20-ish comments on the question, many of which were ad hominem and all sorts of nasty stuff.

This type of lock is temporary while the issue is being [resolved on meta](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/682/961). Once the discrepancy is resolved the post will be unlocked and dealt with accordingly.

---

*Just as a general note to all parties involved, please remember to be [civil and respectful](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) to others.*

**Rudeness will not be tolerated.**

### Period.

Comment: "Rudeness will not be tolerated". There are certain members who are particularly inflammatory - I sometimes lean in that direction when I am attacked, but I try to stick to topic, albeit, using some irony or backhanded attacks, but there are some others, I will not mention names, who seem very prone to inflammatory language and  ad hominem attacks simply because they find another's opinion unpalatable or incorrect, without previous provocation. IMO these members should be admonished and perhaps penalized.